# MLflow saves models to relative place instead of tracking_uri

Tags: mlflow

sorry if my question is too basic, but cannot solve it.
I am experimenting with mlflow currently and facing the following issue:

Even if I have set the *tracking_uri*, the mlflow artifacts are saved to the *./mlruns/...* folder relative to the path from where I run `mlfow run path/to/train.py` (in command line). The mlflow server searches for the artifacts following the *tracking_uri* (`mlflow server --default-artifact-root here/comes/the/same/tracking_uri`).

Through the following example it will be clear what I mean:

I set the following in the training script before the `with mlflow.start_run() as run:`

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("file:///home/@myUser/@SomeFolders/mlflow_artifact_store/mlruns/")
```

My expectation would be that mlflow saves all the artifacts to the place I gave in the registry uri. Instead, it saves the artifacts relative to place from where I run `mlflow run path/to/train.py`, i.e. running the following

```
/home/@myUser/ mlflow run path/to/train.py
```

creates the structure:

```
/home/@myUser/mlruns/@experimentID/@runID/artifacts
/home/@myUser/mlruns/@experimentID/@runID/metrics
/home/@myUser/mlruns/@experimentID/@runID/params
/home/@myUser/mlruns/@experimentID/@runID/tags
```

and therefore it doesn't find the run artifacts in the tracking_uri, giving the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 59, in <module>
    with mlflow.start_run() as run:
  File "/home/@myUser/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-ff56d6062d031d43990effc19450800e72b9830b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 204, in start_run
    active_run_obj = client.get_run(existing_run_id)
  File "/home/@myUser/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-ff56d6062d031d43990effc19450800e72b9830b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 151, in get_run
    return self._tracking_client.get_run(run_id)
  File "/home/@myUser/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-ff56d6062d031d43990effc19450800e72b9830b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 57, in get_run
    return self.store.get_run(run_id)
  File "/home/@myUser/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-ff56d6062d031d43990effc19450800e72b9830b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/file_store.py", line 524, in get_run
    run_info = self._get_run_info(run_id)
  File "/home/@myUser/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-ff56d6062d031d43990effc19450800e72b9830b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/file_store.py", line 544, in _get_run_info
    "Run '%s' not found" % run_uuid, databricks_pb2.RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Run '788563758ece40f283bfbf8ba80ceca8' not found
2021/07/23 16:54:16 ERROR mlflow.cli: === Run (ID '788563758ece40f283bfbf8ba80ceca8') failed ===
```

Why is that so? How can I change the place where the artifacts are stored, this directory structure is created? I have tried `mlflow run --storage-dir here/comes/the/path`, setting the *tracking_uri*, *registry_uri*. If I run the `/home/path/to/tracking/uri mlflow run path/to/train.py` it works, but I need to run the scripts remotely.

My endgoal would be to change the artifact uri to an NFS drive, but even in my local computer I cannot do the trick.

Thanks for reading it, even more thanks if you suggest a solution! :)
Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was solved by the following:

I have mixed the *tracking_uri* with the *backend_store_uri*.

The *tracking_uri* is where the MLflow related data (e.g. tags, parameters, metrics, etc.) are saved, which can be a database. On the other hand, the *artifact_location* is where the artifacts (other, not MLflow related data belonging to the preprocessing/training/evaluation/etc. scripts).
What led me to mistakes is that by running mlflow server from command line one should set up for the *--backend-store-uri* the *tracking_uri* (also in the script by setting the *mlflow.set_tracking_uri()*) and for *--default-artifact-location* the location of the artifacts. Somehow I didn't get that the *tracking_uri* = *backend_store_uri*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

1. Launch the server

```
mlflow server -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 --backend-store-uri postgresql://DB_USER:DB_PASSWORD@DB_ENDPOINT:5432/DB_NAME --default-artifact-root s3://S3_BUCKET_NAME
```

2. Set the the tracking uri to an HTTP URI like

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://my-tracking-server:5000/")
```